# Mensaje de validación no desaparece al validar JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un formulario de contacto donde los mensajes de validación de los inputs aparecen correctamente, si no se ha ingresado el campo name, al ingresarlo, el mensaje de error permanece. 
Y en el campo de validación de email, si se ingresa el email incompleto aparece el mensaje .err_email-1 pero si no se ingresa nada en el campo aparecen los dos errores .err_email-1 y .err_email cómo hacer para que .err_name aparezca sólo cuando el campo está vacío y el .err_email-1 sólo cuando el ingreso es inválido.

```js
function control() {

        $('.err_name').hide();
        $('.err_email').hide();
        $('.err_email-1').hide()
        $('.err_sub').hide();
        $('.err_mes').hide();
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var subject = $('#subject').val();
        var message = $('#message').val();
        name = jQuery.trim(name);
        email = jQuery.trim(email);
        subject = jQuery.trim(subject);
        message = jQuery.trim(message);


        if(name == "") {
            $('.err_name').fadeIn(100);
            $('#name').val(name);
        }
        if(email == "") {
            $('.err_email').fadeIn(100);
            $('#email').val(email);
        }
        if(subject == "") {
            $('.err_sub').fadeIn(100);
            $('#subject').val(subject);
        }
        if(message == "") {
            $('.err_mes').fadeIn(100);
            $('#message').val(message);
        }   
         function validateEmail(email) {
              var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
              return emailReg.test( email );
            }
      if( !validateEmail(email)) {
          $('.err_email-1').fadeIn(100);
          $('#email').val(email);
      }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="send" id="contactForm" >
    <fieldset>                              
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label for="name">Nombre *
                    <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="150" class="form-control" id="name" required></label>
                    <span class="alert alert-danger err_name">*Completar este campo.</span> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label for="email">E-mail *
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" maxlength="150" class="form-control" required></label>
                    <span class="alert alert-danger err_email">*Ingresar Email.</span>   
                    <span class="alert alert-danger err_email-1">*El email no válido!</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label for="phone">Teléfono (Opcional)
                    <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" maxlength="50" class="form-control"></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <label for="subject">Asunto *
                    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" maxlength="50" maxlength="200" class="form-control" required></label>
                    <span class="alert alert-danger err_sub">*Ingrese un asunto.</span>   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label for="message">Mensaje *</label>
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" maxlength="800" rows="8" class="form-control" required></textarea>
                 <span class="alert alert-danger err_mes">*Su Mensaje.</span>                                           
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

        <a href="javascript:control();" id="btn" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>ENVIAR</a>

        </div>
        <hr>
    </div>
    <div id="info"></div> 
</form>
```

Comment: podrias poner el codigo html de tu formulario y donde pintas el error?

Comment: Mete el if en el que compruebas la Regex `if( !validateEmail(email)) {...}` dentro de un `else` en la comparación del email vacio `if(email== "") {...} else if( !validateEmail(email)) {...}`

Comment: @ManuelAlbertoGomezLozano Agregado el html, los mensajes de error aparecen correctamente si se dejan vacios los campos, el problema es cuando un campo se deja vacío aparece el mensaje de error correspondiente y al rellarlo correctamente el mensaje de error continua no desaparece como deberia.

Comment: Tienes una etiqueta `label` cerrando `</label>` de mas, a tu JS le faltan 2 llaves de cierre `}}` y algún `;`, por lo demás he metido tu código en el snippet y no consigo simular el error.

Comment: @x3k_js https://codepen.io/blooppop/pen/QWWBmJa fijate en este codepen ahi puedes ver que el texto de error aparece pero al validar el campo continua, cuando deberia desaparecer

Comment: no será que estas escribiendo un correo que no funciona con la regex? asd@example.com funciona...

Comment: no es especificamente sobre el email, el código de @ManuelAlbertoGomezLozano solucionó eso, lo que se pretende es que luego de que aparezcan los mensajes de error de cada campo desaparezca cada error al validarlo completandolo y no haciendo el click en el submit, sino al corregirlo.

Comment: Entonces tendrás que hacer un evento `change` y ejecutar la validación correspondiente...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cambie tu liga para enviar por un botón, y acomode 2 llaves de cierre que tenias mal, fuera de eso tu código me funciona bien. Pruebalo**

```js
function control() {

  $('.err_name').hide();
  $('.err_email').hide();
  $('.err_email-1').hide()
  $('.err_sub').hide();
  $('.err_mes').hide();
  var name = $('#name').val();
  var email = $('#email').val();
  var subject = $('#subject').val();
  var message = $('#message').val();
  name = jQuery.trim(name);
  email = jQuery.trim(email);
  subject = jQuery.trim(subject);
  message = jQuery.trim(message);


  if(name == "") {
      $('.err_name').fadeIn(100);
      $('#name').val(name);
  }
  if(email == "") {
      $('.err_email').fadeIn(100);
      $('#email').val(email);
  }
  if(subject == "") {
      $('.err_sub').fadeIn(100);
      $('#subject').val(subject);
  }
  if(message == "") {
      $('.err_mes').fadeIn(100);
      $('#message').val(message);
  }

  if( !validateEmail(email)) {
    $('.err_email-1').fadeIn(100);
      //$('#email').val(email);
  }
}   

function validateEmail(email) {
  var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
  return emailReg.test( email );
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" action="send" id="contactForm" >
<fieldset>                              
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="name">Nombre *
                <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="150" class="form-control" id="name" required  onkeyup="control();"></label>
                <span class="alert alert-danger err_name">*Completar este campo.</span> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="email">E-mail *
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" maxlength="150" class="form-control" required onkeyup="control();"></label>
                <span class="alert alert-danger err_email">*Ingresar Email.</span>   
                <span class="alert alert-danger err_email-1">*El email no válido!</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="phone">Teléfono (Opcional)
                <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" maxlength="50" class="form-control"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <label for="subject">Asunto *</label>
                <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" maxlength="50" maxlength="200" class="form-control" required onkeyup="control();"></label>
                <span class="alert alert-danger err_sub">*Ingrese un asunto.</span>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label for="message">Mensaje *</label>
                <textarea name="message" id="message" maxlength="800" rows="8" class="form-control" required onkeyup="control();" ></textarea>
             <span class="alert alert-danger err_mes">*Su Mensaje.</span>                                           
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <button type="button" onclick="control()">ENVIAR</button>

    </div>
    <hr>
</div>
<div id="info"></div> 
</form>
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias!

Comment: de nada, lo que se te ofresca

Comment: tu codigo funciona bien pero con el onkeyup se está enviando solo sin hacer el click en el boton enviar. https://codepen.io/blooppop/pen/QWWBmJa Aquí está el código completo.